# LIMIT within ARRAY_AGG in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When I put a `LIMIT` clause in an `ARRAY_AGG`, I still get many items in the array. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) suggest that this should work.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
SELECT
  x,
  ARRAY_AGG((
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT y
    LIMIT
      1)) y
FROM
  `a`,
  UNNEST(b) b
WHERE
  x = 'abc' 
GROUP BY
  1
LIMIT 1
```

...produces a result with one row of `STRING` an `ARRAY` with 50 items, when I would have expected only 1 item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the placement of the `LIMIT` clause. It was in scope for the `SELECT` statement, rather than the `ARRAY_AGG` function. This corrected it:

```
SELECT
  x,
  ARRAY_AGG((
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT y
    ) LIMIT 1) y
FROM
  `a`,
  UNNEST(b) b
WHERE
  x = 'abc' 
GROUP BY
  1
LIMIT 1
```